UWP Project in Xamarin Forms Works on C Drive Only in VS 2019
If I create an empty Xamarin Forms project on the C drive, the UWP empty GUI opens. If the solution is created on any other drive get an Exception in System.Private.CoreLib.dll. Cannot get the symbols to load, so have no more debug info than that.
If I then copy the non-working copy to the C drive it gives the FileNotFoundException (below) - there is a checkbox to disable System.Private.CoreLib from throwing the error. It then works, however if I copy this back to the D drive, it fails again.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  HResult=0x80070002
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, IntPtr ptrLoadContextBinder)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, IntPtr ptrLoadContextBinder) in E:\A\_work\216\s\src\mscorlib\src\System\Reflection\RuntimeAssembly.cs:line 353

